# How to strip trailing slash from REQUEST_FILENAME for comparison in a rewrite condition?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

If I request the page http://www.mysite.com/frogs/ and use these rewrite rules:

```
# See if the requested URL is in our cache. If so, serve it
RewriteCond /var/www/cache%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule (.*) /var/www/cache/$1.html [L,QSA]
```

Apache tries to find a file called "frogs/.html", which of course fails. I want to use %{REQUEST_FILENAME} without the trailing slash, so that it instead looks for and serves "frogs.html".

How can I make it do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

Test this. It should strip out a trailing slash:

```
RewriteCond /var/www/cache/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/*$ /var/www/cache/$1.html [L, QSA]
```

The reason is that you can backreference the regex in parenthesis in a RewriteRule from the RewriteCond. See [mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#InternalBackRefs) for more info on the backreferencing flow.

Comment: How does that affect the RewriteCond?

Comment: The rewrite condition is just checking to see if the request filename exists in the cache, correct? It shouldn't affect that. The first line I have will rewrite to add .html if there is no slash, and the second will rewrite without the slash if one is present. I'm sure theres a way to do it in one line, but I'm not that gifted in RegEx.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying. I misread your question a bit. Gimme a minute...

Comment: @Nick Take a look at the edit.

Comment: Thanks, It seems to be working! I changed it to "RewriteRule ^/(.*)/$" since "RewriteRule ^/(.+)/*$" wasn't working?

Comment: Odd that it didn't work that way, the regex should have matched. Glad it's fixed though!